# Social share widget to share paragraphs

Tags: twitter, google-plus, facebook-social-plugins

I'm looking for a social widget/plugin similar to that shown when hovering over paragrpahs at metrolyrics, that allows to like/tweet/g+ that specific portion of the lyric:

http://www.metrolyrics.com/all-of-me-lyrics-john-legend.html

Does anyone know if there's something like that available?

Thanks,
Kento.

Answer (score 0):

Refer facebook and twitter API
you can make it as your own

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://dev.twitter.com/